# TomCat: opening file using classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, file-io

I want to open a file on disk when I run a server application on Tomcat. When I print my classpath I get

```
C:\JavaDev\tools\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\bin\bootstrap.jar;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\lib\tools.jar
```

which makes little sense to me, but then again I don't even have a basic understanding how it works. Where are my projects loaded from? Don't they need to be on the classpath?

This is the directory layout of the domain I'm currently working on:

```
src/main/java/com/company/product/domain/b/beans/MyClass.java
src/main/resources/whatever/myfile.txt
```

I've tried opening the file using variations along the lines of:

```
String filename = "../resources/whatver/myfile.txt";
URL url = MyClass.class.getResource(filename);
```

Alas `url==null` every time. Among other path variations I've tried:

```
whatver/myfile.txt
../whatver/myfile.txt
../../../../../../../resources/whatver/myfile.txt
```

I need a solution that I can commit (i.e. not stored in the Eclipse workspace), so not all team members have to update their settings.

This the environment I'm using:

- Tomcat 6.0
- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Helios Service Release 2
- Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 18:31:09+0100)

Answer (score 1):

In a Maven project, the files in `resources` are usually packaged in the classpath somewhere.  Try this:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("whatever/myfile.txt");
```

Is this a web application that gets packaged by Maven as a .war?